# How can I put styles on data list after server-side processing?

Tags: jquery, css, datatables, server-side

I want to put a style on a particular data after server-side processing on datatables.
I use the `wrap()` to do that but it doesn't work.

```js
"fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
        if (aData[4] == 'service stopped'){
          console.log('here');
          $(aData[4]).wrap('<span class="badge-sm badge-danger"></span>');
        }
      },
```

This gave me 3 'here' which is right but the '' doesn't show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So only way to pass from

```
aData[4] == 'service stopped'
```

is if aData[4] is a string literal of 'service stopped'. So

```
$(aData[4]).wrap
```

should likely be

```
$('td:eq(4)', nRow).wrap
```

as instead of a string it is wrapping row n on 4th column.